# iPhone: whether it is possible to make video programmatically

Tags: iphone, video, capture

i want to create a video programmatically using iPhone camera. i can take a picture programmatically . but about video i am not sure. so please suggest whether it is possible or not ? if yes, then please guide me or provide me some useful link

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the device supports it.  In fact, you use the same APIs that you would to capture the camera stills.

Have a look at the [Setting Required Hardware Capabilities](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedFeatures/AdvancedFeatures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH14-SW59) article as well as [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView) and [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html), they have been updated for 3.1

Answer (score 1):

It is possible only in iPhone 3GS. iPhone 3G doesn't support video capture.

[UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) is the class you are looking for. It allows you to take pictures (on 3G and 3GS) and record videos (on 3GS).